# chrome-aws-lambda + lighthouse always results in NO_SCREENSHOTS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, chromium, lighthouse

I am trying to run Lighthouse via Puppeteer in a `public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs` Docker image using `chrome-aws-lambda`, and no matter what website I send to Lighthouse, I always get errors like this:

> Chrome didn't collect any screenshots during the page load. Please m
> ake sure there is content visible on the page, and then try re-running Lighthouse. (NO_SCREENSHOTS)

Note that I've tried sending it VERY fast loading pages like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), so other tips online related to this error that claim the site is just too slow doesn't seem correct to me.

`/Dockerfile`

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:latest
RUN cd /var/task/ & npm install puppeteer-core chrome-aws-lambda lighthouse --save-prod
RUN cd /var/task/ & npm install puppeteer --save-dev
```

`/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  lighthouse:
    build:
      context: .
    networks:
      - lighthousenetwork
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./task/:/var/task/:delegated
    command: index.handler

networks:
  lighthousenetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

`/task/index.js`

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let response = null;
    let browser = null;

    try {
        browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
            args: [...chromium.args, "--remote-debugging-port=9222"],
            defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
            executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
            headless: chromium.headless,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        });

        const options = {
            output: "json",
            preset: 'mobile',
            onlyCategories: ["performance", "seo", "accessibility", "best-practices"],
            port: 9222,
        }

        const url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event';

        const result = await lighthouse(url, options);
        console.log(`Audited ${url} in ${result.lhr.timing.total} ms.`);

        const report = JSON.parse(result.report);

        response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: {
                'url': url,
                'Performance': report['categories']['performance']['score'],
                'Accessibility': report['categories']['accessibility']['score'],
                'SEO': report['categories']['seo']['score'],
                'BestPractices': report['categories']['best-practices']['score'],
                'ErrorMessage': report['audits']['speed-index']['errorMessage']
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(error);
    } finally {
        if (browser !== null) {
            await browser.close();
        }
    }

    return callback(null, response);
};
```

**Start the Docker container:**

```
$ docker-compose up
```

**Trigger the function handler:**

```
$ curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8080/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"payload":"hello world!"}'
```

**Output:**

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":{"url":"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event","Performance":null,"Accessibility":0.91,"SEO":0.89,"BestPractices":1,"ErrorMessage":"Chrome didn't collect any screenshots during the page load. Please make sure there is content visible on the page, and then try re-running Lighthouse. (NO_SCREENSHOTS)"}}
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that `lighthouse` can not connect to the browser instance through port `9222`. I am really not sure if AWS Lambda allows opening ports etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue. Did a bunch of things, like passing in different flags to chrome, lighthouse. None works.

Then i found this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/10483/files#diff-b745a09f9adfeb967c49c66acad7fdcaR77

Seems like lighthouse team doesn't really recommend lambda env.

I see other ppl running into same issue:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/12101
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13021

Ye i suggest move away from lambda for now. Try running lighthouse on a cluster or something.

Not really a solution to fix the error you see. But just want to share what i found on this.